# Error in installing Mesos.make and make check works fine but its giving an error while running make install

Tags: installation, cluster-computing, make-install, mesos

Error in installing Mesos.make and make check works fine but its giving an error while running make install

```
/bin/mkdir -p '/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/include/mesos'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../../include/mesos/executor.hpp ../../include/mesos/scheduler.hpp ../../include/mesos/mesos.proto '/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/include/mesos'
/usr/bin/install: `../../include/mesos/executor.hpp' and `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/include/mesos/executor.hpp' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `../../include/mesos/scheduler.hpp' and `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/include/mesos/scheduler.hpp' are the same file
/usr/bin/install: `../../include/mesos/mesos.proto' and `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/include/mesos/mesos.proto' are the same file
make[3]: *** [install-pkgincludeHEADERS] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/build/src'
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/build/src'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/nitk/mesos-0.13.0/build/src'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you should ask a more specific question, and give more information about your environment and what else you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This error is normally seen if your instance is has a small amount of memory available switching to a bigger instance should solve this issue. EC2 minimum instance should be a medium.